# Convert decimal degrees to meters QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, utm

I am working in QGIS 3.4.8-Madeira on MacOS 10.14. I simply want to create a buffer on a point shapefile, but the layer is not being read in UTM but in degrees. I understand this is a common question but am having trouble with solutions I have found. I want the CRS to EPSG:32642/WGS 1984 UTM 42N (Afghanistan).

My steps to change the CRS were to:

1. Set project CRS (EPSG:32642/WGS 1984 UTM 42N);
2. Import the .csv with the desired CRS;
3. Save the .csv as a .shp with the desired CRS.

I have tried this set of steps several times. While the .qgz and the .prj of the shapefile all state they are in EPSG 32642, my points keep rendering at 0,0, and coordinates are still in decimal degrees rather than meters. I believe the source of this issue may be in the .csv formatting. How do I convert the decimal degrees to meters? Apologies for the question repetition.

Comment: What do the coordinates in the CSV look like? Are they in lat/long?

Comment: Yes, they are in lat/lon in the form of [34.98735, 63.12891]. The .csv data type is double

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First import the data in the CSV it's actually in. Once the data is imported, then you can *reproject* it into the desired CRS.**

The coordinates in your CSV are in latitude and longitude. This means they're actually in a *geographic coordinate system*. The standard/most commonly used geographic CRS is EPSG:4326.

Here's how your workflow *should* go (with the same step numbers as your current workflow):

1. It doesn't matter what your project CRS is.
2. Import your CSV, with its CRS as EPSG:4326.
3. Look at your map and make sure the points are in the correct place. Reproject the data into the desired CRS by saving it as a .shp with the desired CRS.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see where I went wrong.

Comment: @jb12 if this answered your question, please accept it using the tick between the voting arrows https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers